# Manual UWB ranging specs configuration

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, uwb

I am building an app that will set up a ranging session between 2 android phones that support UWB, without using any OOB mechanism like BLE, WiFi etc., but hard coding the parameters.

I initiate the session on both the controller and the controlee and when I try to add the controlee to the ranging session the app crashes.

```
        val uwbManager = UwbManager.createInstance(applicationContext)
        var job: Job?
        val uwbDevice = UwbDevice.createForAddress("42:43")

         val uwbChannel = UwbComplexChannel(5,9)

         fun doSomethingWithThePosition(context: RangingPosition) {
             println("Ranging position obtained: ")
         }

         fun handlePeerDisconnect(rangingResult: RangingResult.RangingResultPeerDisconnected) {
             println("Peer has disconnected")
         }

        suspend fun startRanging() {
            val controllerSession = uwbManager.controllerSessionScope()

            //val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())

           val partnerParameters = RangingParameters(
               uwbConfigType = RangingParameters.CONFIG_UNICAST_DS_TWR,
               sessionId = 0,
               subSessionId = 0,
               sessionKeyInfo = null,
               subSessionKeyInfo = null,
               complexChannel = uwbChannel,
               peerDevices = listOf(uwbDevice),
               updateRateType = RangingParameters.RANGING_UPDATE_RATE_AUTOMATIC
           )
            
            val sessionFlow = controllerSession.prepareSession(partnerParameters)
            
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main.immediate).launch {
                sessionFlow.collect {
                    when(it) {
                        is RangingResult.RangingResultPosition -> {
                            doSomethingWithThePosition(it.position)
                        }
                        is RangingResult.RangingResultPeerDisconnected -> handlePeerDisconnect(it)
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                // ADD A CONTROLEE, PASS ITS UWB_ADDRESS
                controllerSession.addControlee(uwbDevice.address)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "An exception occured when adding a controlee", e)
            }
        }
         
         var rangingResult = RangingResult.RangingResultPosition(device = uwbDevice, position = RangingPosition(
             distance = null, elevation = null, azimuth = null, elapsedRealtimeNanos = 0
         ))
```

Tried adding a controlee with fixed parameters, however I get an error:

```
An exception occured when adding a controlee
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please check that the ranging is active and theranging profile supports multi-device ranging. 
at androidx.core.uwb.impl.UwbControllerSessionScopeImpl.addControlee(UwbControllerSessionScopeImpl.kt:47) 
at androidx.core.uwb.impl.UwbControllerSessionScopeImpl$addControlee$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15) 
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
```

Even though before that, i receive this log:

```
com.example.controllerrangingapp 
Creating Gms Client session scope
```